# React-Native Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, state

native developers! I've got some problems: I'm trying to make a GET request and when I want to display it I get error: Cannot read property 'door_state' of undefined. What could be wrong, could you explain, please? My GetApartments class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

class GetApartments extends Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        apartments: []
      }
 }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.getApartmentsFromApi().then((res) => {
        this.setState(() => ({
          apartments : res
        }));
      });
  }

  async getApartmentsFromApi() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
    'http://ec2-13-59-148-153.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/flat'
      );
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    let door = this.state.apartments[0].door_state;
    return(
      <View> <Text>{door}</Text> </View>
    )
  }

}
```

And here is my Apartments page where I try to display the data:

```
export default class ApartmentsPage extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <GetApartments />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

With best regards.

Comment: See the linked question's answers. Basically, `render` is called before you have any entries in `this.state.apartments`, thus `this.state.apartments[0]` results in `undefined`, and so you get the error trying to read `door_state` from it. Your ajax call in `componentDidMount` will not hold up rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To be honest, I have basic knowledge of JavaScript and I'd like to resume: when I render ApartmentsPage, the GetApartments class can't get in time, right? So, In order to fix this, I have to render GetApartments class before ApartmentsPage? By the way, I replaced componentDidMount() to componentWillMount().

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Forgot to mention you in the previous comment. So, when I try to render GetApartments class: ReactDOM.render(<GetApartments />, document.getElementById('root'));  , I get an error which says: document is not defined.

Comment: Please see the linked question's answers about what to do, it's covered there. Re your "document is not defined," presumably `document` isn't a predefined global in React Native. Follow a React Native tutorial to find out how to render your component.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hats off to you, sir!